# Как использовать RETURNING при дампе базы с csv файла

Tags: postgresql, psql

Я пытаюсь запарсить данные из csv файла в postgresql через psql, но я не понял как правильно написать query для записи данных в таблицу из csv которая должна возвращать id который я сразу же запишу в другую таблицу для связки ManyToOne

Вот пример записи в одну таблицу

```
\copy table1(column1, column2...) from 'path' delimiter ';' csv header
```

Comment: On successful completion, a `COPY` command returns a command tag of the form `COPY count` The `count` is the number of rows copied. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-copy.html#id-1.9.3.55.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Напрямую никак. Нужно делать через временную таблицу:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE table1_temp (...);

\copy table1_temp(column1, column2...) from 'path' delimiter ';' csv header

INSERT INTO table1
SELECT * FROM table1_temp;

# тут используем результат предыдущего COPY из table1_temp 
# для того, чтобы вставить записи в связанные таблицы

DROP TABLE table1_temp;
```